# how to intercept gesture for a sibling view?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

if there are three views:

```
view1
    ---subview1
    ---subview2
```

normally, subview2 will handle every gesture, however, in my case, I just need the subview2 to handle pinch gesture, and other gestures like pan and rotate will pass to subview1, is there any way to do it?

Comment: Is subview2 on top of subview1?

Answer (score 0):

implement this method from the [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate-Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer%3ashouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer%3a):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return true;
}
```